# System.Net.Http from visual studio's assemblies vs nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am considering which is the difference between tis two packages. If i will search in references of visual studio i will find System.Net.Http.dll version 4.0.
But if i will look into nuget packages i will find a version 4.3.4.
Both of them are work very nice. But which of two is better to use visual studio or from nuget?
Thank you

Comment: The latter version has potentially more features, less bugs and better cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: So you suggest me to install latest version from nuget than default visual studio's edition. Why dll from references doent have the same version?

Comment: If you bring the NuGet version into a .NET Framework (i.e., not Core) project, you risk descending into the depths of "NuGet Hell". A complex Framework-based project that NuGets in that assembly often ends up having circular dependencies and/or an astounding number of bindingredirect entries. If you dig around long enough, you'll find a posting from someone at MSFT apologizing for that package

Comment: Which is better to use with your experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you are seeing in Visual Studio is predicated on the version you are running of .Net.  Each version of .Net Core's SDK could potentially have a different version of `System.Net.Http.dll`.  What you are seeing in Nuget is the latest version, which does not appear to match the version for your currently used .Net SDK.

Comment: Which is better to use?

Comment: Theoretically, the latest release of any software should be the best option.  It has bugs fixed, security gaps patched, and new features incorporated.  The reality is that not all packages releases are compatible with one another.  So if you run an older version of the .Net Core SDK and upgrade that single package, then it may not work with the other packages you are using.  Updating your SDK to the latest will give you access to all of the latest packages as a whole.